# Import, Cannot get autoincrement value

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport

I've been running a csv import into magento and getting the error `Cannot get autoincrement value`

Currently I've done the following to try and resolve the problem:
Gone into the database and make sure dataflow_profile_history & dataflow_batch has auto increment enabled via phpMyAdmin
Exported current product list and reimport it, getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was based on the database. The fields which required auto increment hadn't been correctly set to do so.

Recommend to create a new magento installation, and then export just the database structure while making sure that auto increment option is selected on the export, then import this for the database currently in use.